# Display Form Input Value With CoffeeScript in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

**Original Question**: I'm working towards validation of a user's email with a regular expression after the event of ***'focusout'*** in javascript, but for right now I'm trying to simply get to the point where I can grab the value that was inputted into the field:

code so far:

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
    $user_email = $('#user_email_form')

    $user_email.on 'focusout', ->
        alert($user_email.val)
```

What I want this to do is simply display the text that was entered into an alert box, but instead it is displaying a whole bunch of javascript in the alert box.

**Answer**

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->

    $(".phone_form").mask("(999) 999-9999")
    $(".ssn_form").mask("999-99-9999");

    $('#user_email_form').on 'focusout', ->
        alert($(@).val())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `val()` as a function as so: `$user_email.val()`

Also, when you do `.on`, you get the target as this, so you can just do this.

```
$user_email.on 'focusout', ->
  val = $(@).val()
```